# How to get cumulative sum till current month?

Tags: powerbi

| Month | value |
| --- | --- |
| January 2023 | 2 |
| February 2023 | 4 |
| March 2023 | 0 |

I want the cumulative sum till current month and 0 after that. how do i do this in power bi

```
January 2023 2
February 2023 6
there should be no march
```

I tried few things but it's calculating for March as well and displaying 6

```
Actuals running total in Month 2: = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('BI_ClientAdoptionReport'[Actuals]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('BI_ClientAdoptionReport'[Month]),
        ISONORAFTER('BI_ClientAdoptionReport'[Month], MAX('BI_ClientAdoptionReport'[Month]), DESC)
    )
)
```

Comment: add your DAX expression, then it will be easier to get the point.

Answer (score 2):

Use this measure instead:

```
Actuals running total in Month = 
VAR running_total = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('BI_ClientAdoptionReport'[Actuals]),
        FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED('BI_ClientAdoptionReport'[Month]),
            ISONORAFTER(
                'BI_ClientAdoptionReport'[Month], 
                MAX('BI_ClientAdoptionReport'[Month]), 
                DESC
            )
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( 
        SELECTEDVALUE(BI_ClientAdoptionReport[Actuals]) = 0, 
        0, 
        running_total 
    )
```

[image]

Comment: This is correct, but needs one small adjustment.  The user does not want march to appear, so the `IF` statement should return `BLANK()` instead of `0`.

Comment: The OP "want the cumulative sum till current month and 0 after that". I took the question literally.

Comment: ah, you’re correct. I zeroed in on ‘ there should be no march’ in the result example. I guess they have both answers now. :)